# Problem with locked door

Tags: locks, door, jetta

The front door of our Jetta is stuck and cannot be unlocked. Has Anybody had a similar experience and does anyone know how can I get it unlocked please?

Comment: Was the car in an accident?

Comment: What year is your Jetta? Is it actually locked, or is the latching mechanism not working? When you flip the switch from locked to unlocked and back, does it feel the same as it used to? Does it have a remote (fob) with electric locks? If so, do you hear anything in the door when you press the button?

Comment: If I had to guess the locking mechanism in the latch is jammed in the halfway position so the latch wouldn't work and the latch won't unlock. If you're feeling adventurous you can pull back the door panel and try using a long screwdriver or rod to unlock the latch.

Comment: Car was in accident a year ago but this door was not damaged, one of the other doors had to be replaced then.

Comment: The Jetta is 2009 model. When I press the remote, the door makes a slight sound but does not unlock. The outside handle cannot move and the inside handle is very stiff when trying to open manually. Does not unlock the door.  I think I may have tried to open the door with the outside handle before the remote unlocked the door fully when the problem started.

Comment: Your either going to have to peel back the door panel, have a shop do it or maybe a locksmith would be able to help you. If you lower the window and pull the panel back you should be able to see the latch. Sometimes the locking/latching mechanisms can be seen sometimes they're hidden under plastic. Either way something in the latch/lock mechanism is jammed and needs to be unjammed.

Comment: It might be that the lock mechanism needs lubrication, I had a car with a similar problem.

Comment: What year is your car?

Comment: Voting to close, No activity for 3 months and we'd need more information to be helpful – beyond pull the door panel off and look to see what seems to be out of whack.

Comment: @dlu Agreed - but OP can't pull the door panel off if they can't open the door! Bit of a sticky situation. Hi-jinx. Benny Hill. OP should still be able to pull the handle itself off and spray some silicone based lube in there to see if it frees anything up.